# Try to run a web application with a html page in Intellij IDEA but get 404 error

Tags: html, tomcat, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I want to do simple thing: let user input username and password, then show it on second page. I use tomcat 8 as server. Here are key codes:

**login.html:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
        <title>login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div align="center"><h1>login in</h1>

        <form  method="post" action="GetPostData" name="login form" align="center">
            <table align="center" width="232" border="2">
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="Reset">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
        </form>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GetPostData</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ywwynm.GetPostData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GetPostData</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/GetPostData</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**GetPostData.java:**

```
package com.ywwynm;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "GetPostData")
public class GetPostData extends HttpServlet {

    public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(
                "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n"+
                        "<H1 ALIGN=CENTER>" +"GetPostData"+"</H1><br>"+
                        "<UL>\n"+
                        "<L1><B>username:"+request.getParameter("username")+"<br>"+
                        "<L1><B>password:"+request.getParameter("password")+"<br>"+
                        "</UL>"+"\n"+
                        "</BODY>"+
                        "</HTML>"
        );
        out.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }
}
```

But when I click run on login.html, it only shows a static web page login.html. After I input informations and click submit, 404 error will jump into the page.

I've already set the compiled class directory to web/WEB-INF/classes.

**Some clues:**

1. The url of running login.html doesn't start with localhost:**8080** but another number.
2. Intellij reminded me that cannot resolve file "GetPostData" in login.html(at `action="GetPostData"`).
3. I clicked run on login.html but didn't find approach to run the whole module.

I Googled how to develop web application by Intellij but nearly all of them took auto-generated index.jsp as the example. As a result, I don't know if I should do other preparations to make all work. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found that my login.html isn't in folder `web`. I move it into `web` and  everything works well.